# Control uploads to S3 using BFTask and AWS SDK iOS v2

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using [BFTask](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS) together with [AWS SDK v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v2) for iOS to upload and download files to AWS S3 storage. The following code works very well but I am wondering if anyone know how I can gain more control over the maximum number of uploads to allow and also better approach to receiving feedback for upload progress. I have read the documentation for both AWS SDK v2, the source code, and the BFTask readme but I am still uncertain how I gain control. For example, how would I edit the following code to limit the number of BFTasks to be run simultaneously to 3 and also receive number of bytes currently uploaded out of total number of bytes?

```
-(void) uploadAllFileRequests
{
    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
    __block int uploadCount = 0;
    __block int uploadSuccess= 0;
    __block int uploadFailure= 0;

    NSMutableArray *tasks = [NSMutableArray new];
    unsigned long totalnumberoffiles=self.arrayOfUploadRequests.count;

    for (__block AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequestLocal in self.arrayOfUploadRequests)
    {

        [tasks addObject:[[transferManager upload:uploadRequestLocal] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            if (task.error != nil) {
                 if( task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled
                   &&
                   task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused
                   )
                {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",StatusLabelFailed);
                    uploadFailure ++;
                }
            } else {
                uploadCount ++;
                uploadSuccess ++;
                NSLog(@"ETag: %@           %@ : %3.2f",[task.result valueForKey:@"ETag"], StatusLabelUploading, (uploadCount*1.0/totalnumberoffiles)*100.);
            }
            return nil;     
        }]];
    }
    [[BFTask taskForCompletionOfAllTasks:tasks] continueWithSuccessBlock:^id(BFTask *task)
     {
         NSLog(@"Finished:  Success: %i - Failed: %i  -",uploadSuccess,uploadFailure);
         return nil;
     }];
}
```

Here `self.arrayOfUploadRequests` is an array containing `AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest`. Suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWSRequest`, a superclass of `AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest`, has properties called `uploadProgress` and `downloadProgress`. You can implement `AWSNetworkingUploadProgressBlock` and `AWSNetworkingDownloadProgressBlock` to retrieve the progress feedback.

One way to limit the number of concurrent uploads to three is to sequentially execute three tasks in parallel. You can combine **In sequence** and **In parallel** sections of this [blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2B17V9NSVLP3I/The-AWS-Mobile-SDK-for-iOS-How-to-use-BFTask).