# ASIS3ObjectRequest issue bad url while uploading a file to Amazon

Tags: ios7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

ASIS3ObjectRequest *request =[ASIS3ObjectRequest PUTRequestForData:imagetoUpload withBucket:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"bucketName"] key:uploadKey];
    request.accessPolicy = ASIS3AccessPolicyPublicReadWrite;
[request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

and getting error like this
Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Unable to create request (bad url?)" UserInfo=0x10fa0550 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to create request (bad url?)}

Please suggest me how to upload a file in Amazon Service.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official [AWS SDK v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios-v2) which makes it very easy to upload and download files to S3. Some examples (get started guides) for use of this library is available on Github [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples). The ASIHTTP library is no longer supported (as of 2011) by the developer and it could be wise to switch to AWS SDK for that reason. An example of how to upload to S3 using the SDK is available on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556729/control-uploads-to-s3-using-bftask-and-aws-sdk-ios-v2).
Hope this helps. T.

Comment: WHen i change startAsynchronous to startSynchronous also getting the same issue.

Comment: @SriM Did you follow my advice and switch to AWS SDK v2?

Comment: Actually I should use the older version. Its an instructions given to me. SO that am struggling now..